# Recording and saving audio file becomes weird

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I started building an Electron app that records audio and saves it. I can record the audio, and save it, and then I am also able to play it. But when I play it, something weird happens. This is how it looks like on Groovy player:

[image]

And also in VLC, it shows the same time on the left and right.

This is the code when I stop the recording

```
mediaRecorder.addEventListener("stop", async () => {
  const audioBlob = new Blob(audioChunks, { type: "audio/wav" });
  const buffer = Buffer.from(await audioBlob.arrayBuffer());

  const { filePath } = await dialog.showSaveDialog({
    buttonLabel: "Save Audio",
    defaultPath: `aud-${Date.now()}.wav`,
  });
  writeFile(filePath, buffer, () =>
    console.log("Audio saved successfully")
  );
});
```

I also tried to change it to ogg but still, there's the same problem.
THANKS IN ADVANCE!

Answer (score 0):

I think the cause of error is mismatch between audio codecs.

You can easily reproduce it with following code.

It records a microphone audio for 2 seconds, recreates a new blob with `audio/wav` format and downloads it. It even gets `435:13:24` time right.

```js
(async() => {

  const microphoneAudioStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true });
  const stream = audio.captureStream();
  const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(microphoneAudioStream);

  mediaRecorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', (event) => {
    const blob = event.data;

    const blobType = "audio/wav";
    const extension = "wav";

    //const blobType = blob.type;
    //const extension = "webm";

    const audioBlob = new Blob([blob], { type: blobType });
    const anchor = document.createElement("a");
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(audioBlob);
    anchor.href = url;
    anchor.download = `test.${extension}`;
    anchor.click();
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  });

  mediaRecorder.start();

  setTimeout(() => {
    mediaRecorder.stop();
  }, 2000)

})();
```

In my case I tried to create new blob out of `audio/webm;codecs=opus` data.

There are three solutions.

- You could keep the same format as original blob.
- Append another param to [MediaRecorder constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder/MediaRecorder) which options object with `mimeType`
- Find some API which converts from `audio/webm` to `audio/wav`

Comment: I was trying to follow one tutorial in which he made the screen recorder. He saved the file in webm format and the same thing is happening with his project: I see the video's progressbar is not going ahead and also the time looks somewhat weird. I think it is the default behaviour when you save the file. [video](https://youtu.be/3yqDxhR2XxE?t=121).
You can see the video player is a bit weird.